# probability that at least 349 cables will not break under a force of

Tags: probability

> The minimum force required to break a particular type of cable is
> normally  distributed with mean $12,432$ and standard deviation $25$. A
> random sample of $400$ cables of this type is selected. Calculate the
> probability that at least $349$ of the selected cables will not break
> under a force of $12,400$.

#### Attempt.

Let $X$ be the force required to break a cable. We are given $X \approx N(12432, 25)$. Now, Let $Y$ be the number of cables that will break. We want to find $P(Y < 349)$. We are given $n=400$. Now, to find the probability of success p, notice

$$ p = P(X \geq 12400) = 1 - P(X < 12400) = 1 - P(X \leq 12399.5) $$

Thus,

$$ p = 1-\Phi \left( \frac{12399.5 - 12432}{25} \right) = 1 - \Phi(-1.3) = 0.9032 $$

Now, $Y \approx N( np, \sqrt{npq} )$. We have $\mu = 361.28$ and $\sigma = 5.91$. Thus,

$$ P(Y<349) = P( Y \leq 348.5) = \Phi \left( \frac{ 348.5-361.28}{5.91} \right) = \Phi(-2.16) = 0.0154 $$

But, the answer is supposed to be $\boxed{0.97}$. Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find the probability that at least $349$ of the cables will **not** break. Your solution is correct except for the last part that should be:

$$P(Y\leq 50.5) = \Phi \left( \frac{ 50.5-38.72}{5.91} \right) \approx 0.977, $$

where $38.72=n(1-p).$

Comment: why $50.5$ >????

Comment: $Y$ is the number that break. You want the number that do not break, $400-Y$ to be greater than or equal to $349,$ so $Y\leq 51$ and $Y\leq 50.5$ by continuity adjustment.